# Theme customizer - settings order

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

If I add more than 5 Settings to a single section, the order of the settings gets weird.

For example:

```
// Link color
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'tonal_'.$themeslug.'_settings[link_color1]', array(
    'default'           => $themeOptions['link_color1'],
    'type'              => 'option',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    'transport'         => 'postMessage'
) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'tonal_'.$themeslug.'_settings[link_color1]', array(
    'label'    => __( 'Link color1', 'tonal' ),
    'section'  => 'colors',
    'settings' => 'tonal_'.$themeslug.'_settings[link_color1]',
    'choices'  => '#ffffff'
) ) );
```

<sup>[Further examples in a pastebin - no expiration time](http://pastebin.com/fu916dfS)</sup>

The colors are numbered from 1 to 7, but in the settings they appear in that order: 2,1,3,4,6,5,7

Has anybody experienced the same?

Or does anybody even know how to solve this?

Comment: Sure, that it's spelled "cusomizer"? ;)

Comment: thx... fixed =D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need them in a specific order, then give a priority value to the controls. Otherwise, their order is not defined and cannot be guaranteed.

If you don't define a priority, then the control gets the default priority of "10".

When two controls have the same priority, then the resulting order is undefined, because that's [how PHP works](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Comment: oh my...THAT simple. Didn't know the priority value works on controls aswell. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

### CleanUp

Iterating is much easier for debugging, as you'll see step by step information:

> »What happens, after I added this to that?«

So simply start with a clean up and see *how* it gets added.

```
foreach ( range( 1, 7 ) as $nr )
{
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 
        "tonal_{$themeslug}_settings[link_color{$nr}]",
        array(
            'default'           => $themeOptions[ "link_color{$nr}" ],
            'type'              => 'option',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
            'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
            'transport'         => 'postMessage'
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            "tonal_{$themeslug}_settings[link_color{$nr}]",
            array(
                'label'    => __( sprintf( 'Link color%s', $nr ), 'tonal' ),
                'section'  => 'colors',
                'settings' => "tonal_{$themeslug}_settings[link_color{$nr}]",
                'choices'  => '#ffffff'
            ) 
        ) 
    );

    // DEBUG:
    echo '<pre>'; var_export( $wp_customize, true ); echo '</pre>';
}
```

### Sorting

The chance is pretty high, that you'll get around it with [default php sorting mechanisms](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). Just take a look at the output and than see what you can do with simple array sorting (Hint: You can easily type cast `(array) $object`  and `(object) $array`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. At this point it's all in the right order. The order must get mixed anywhere in the core classes, I think. But I couldn't track it down yet.

Comment: Is this now the right answer? If so, please mark it as solution. The check mark is right below the voting arrows. If not, then please add your own answer and explain the steps you've taken to get around it. Thanks.

Comment: Otto already posted the right answer (which I accepted). `give a priority value to the controls`, I think no further explanation is needed ;-)

Comment: Absolutely agree :)